# Python win32api keybd_event alt key gets stuck

Tags: python, winapi

I am having some trouble with the win32api keybd_event for the ALT key. I am automating a process that requires me to hit ALT-r to open a menu. The only problem is, once ALT-r is hit, the ALT key doesn't release, so all subsequent actions happen as if the alt key is held down. I am using KeyDown and KeyUp in this order:

```
KeyDown(18)
KeyDown(82)
KeyUp(82)
KeyUp(18)
```

This should do ALT pressed, r pressed, r released, ALT released. However, ALT never releases. I have tried all combinations of the above order, I tried putting timer.sleep() in between each line, I tried hitting KeyUp(18) again, and I tried using 0x12 etc instead of 18, and I also tried not depressing ALT at all. Nothing works.

The strange thing is, after my program runs and he ALT key is still stuck, the only way to fix it is by hitting right alt on my keyboard. Right ATL and left ALT both have the same designation in win32api (18 or 0x12), so I cant make my program model this behavior. I feel like I have exhausted all of my ideas, does anyone have any advice?

Comment: If you need to automate a GUI, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Faking input hardly ever ends well.

Comment: you should focus on your window first! then sent your hot-keys ....

Answer (score 0):

Try This ( you should focus on your current window first, then send your hot-keys ):

```
import win32com.client
import win32gui
import win32process
import win32api

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

_, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd) # hwnd is your window id

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

shell.AppActivate(pid)

win32api.sleep(1000)

shell.SendKeys('{UP}{ENTER}')
```